# Which is correct "start time" or "starting time"

Tags: phrase-usage

I'd like to know which of the following is correct:

"start time" or "starting time".

An example is:  He runs during period [*t,t+c*] every afternoon, where *t* is the start (or starting) time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are used, understood, and acceptable.

I personally prefer not to modify a noun with a noun. So, as a matter of style, I'd go with "starting time."

Comment: I prefer 'starting time' too, but Google Ngram Viewer shows that 'start time' has rocketed past 'starting time' in the last 30 years, first in American English, then also in British English. 'finish time' overtook 'finishing time' even earlier (50 years ago).